# KineticJS - basic javascript scope issue

Tags: javascript, scope, kineticjs

Ok, I'm trying to put the javascript in a separate source file. This is a newbie question, but I'm getting an 'undefined' error on `layer.add(imageObj)`.
I'm guessing it's because of `window.onLoad`, but I didn't find an immediate answer.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board"></div>
</body>
```

The javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'board'
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: imageObj,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  });
};
imageObj.src = 'resources/map.jpg';

layer.add(imageObj);
stage.add(layer);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add into layer `Kinetic.Image` instance (`image` in your source) not `imageObj`. You can do this in `onload` function. See: http://jsbin.com/buroyi/2/edit